# Display line number in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, textarea, line

I want to display the line number in a textarea like this is possible in jQuery:

[image]

I looked for answers on SO but I can't find what I want

[Display current line and column number for a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851825/display-current-line-and-column-number-for-a-textarea)

[Limit number of lines in textarea and Display line count using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501043/specify-and-limit-number-of-lines-in-textarea-and-display-line-count-using-jquer)

Also, the solution I tried from the JSFiddle provided from the comments show me the textarea like this:

[image]

which line 1234 is the first line and the second line is 5678

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html adding line numbers to textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995370/html-adding-line-numbers-to-textarea)

Comment: @JamesHill i tried didn't work

Comment: I just copied an pasted into a jsFiddle from the first example and got something working in 30 seconds or less - http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/jMZKz/

Comment: What exactly did you try? The linked thread lists a couple of solutions to your problem. If you have tried to implement one of them and it doesn't work, describe what you've tried already and post the code, so we can help you.

Comment: @Simon i tried the code provided by james

Comment: @aki, the fiddle was an example to get you going. I could be wrong, but I don't think anyone is going to write a fully working piece of code for you. There are plenty of examples coming up in a Google search - try them out. Here's another example using a jquery plugin - http://files.aw20.net/jquery-linedtextarea/jquery-linedtextarea.html

Comment: I've created a pen about this, that works well with line wrapping, although that is using JavaScript. Check it if you want: https://codepen.io/CodemasterUnited/pen/oNQexQp

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Download the plugin found here: http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm

**Usage:**

```
$(function() {

  // Target all classed with ".lined"
  $(".lined").linedtextarea(
    {selectedLine: 1}
  );

  // Target a single one
  $("#mytextarea").linedtextarea();

});
```

Fully functional demo: [http://files.aw20.net/jquery-linedtextarea/jquery-linedtextarea.html (web.archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190220105456/http://files.aw20.net/jquery-linedtextarea/jquery-linedtextarea.html)

Comment: Any solution for those that use `word-wrap: break-word`?

Comment: Provided link appers dead. New link can be found [here](https://github.com/aw20/JQueryLinedText). Tested plugin witj jQuery 1.8 and it did not work properly as browser hangs (Chrome and Firefox).Trying to narrow problem.

Comment: Any chance you updated it to be responsive so the textarea will resize (and take up the width of it's parent)? Regardless, awesome work! I'll try and edit, but it's pretty high-end in that .js file for me! :)